# appengine-web.xml does not contain a <threadsafe> element

Tags: java, google-app-engine

Working on an app engine java application I am getting the error in the subject.

I have looked at similar questions that say that a

```
<threadsafe>true</threadsafe>
```

element should be added to appengine-web.xml, but my appengine-web.xml file is auto generted based on app.yaml and the instructions [here](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/configyaml/appconfig_yaml) do not provide any help...

I think it might be acheived using the instructions re "Custom XML Output" in that same page but they seem to be missing the part on how to actually do it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 'threadsafe' option would need to be appear in a place similar to the 'sessions-enabled' option.  I suggest trying the following additional line in app.yaml after the 'runtime' line:

```
threadsafe: true
```

It's not documented, as you said, but 'sessions_enabled' corresponds to 'sessions-enabled', so it might work.  ("feature!" ;-)

Answer (score 0):

A minimal sample appengine-web.xml file looks like this as found [here](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/config/appconfig):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<appengine-web-app xmlns="http://appengine.google.com/ns/1.0">
<application>_your_app_id_</application>
<version>1</version>
<threadsafe>true</threadsafe>
</appengine-web-app>
```